# Flutter DropdownButton show label when option is selected

Tags: flutter

Can a `Dropdown Button`:

```
 return DropdownButton<String>(
          items: <String>['Foo', 'Bar'].map((String value) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: new Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (_) {},
        );
```

have something similar to a decoration user in a `TextFormField`:

```
      TextFormField(
        controller: _titleController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Input'),
        validator: (String value) {
          if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
        },
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
```

When something is written in the above TextFormField the word `Input` shows. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Replace DropdownButton with DropdownButtonFormField:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html

Comment: `DropdownButtonFormField` unlike `DropdownButton` has padding on tapping which doesn't fire drop down, so if you tap not on the center then nothing happens and you sit guessing why it's not working.. How to make it tappable?

Comment: @temirbek just set 'isExpanded' to true

Comment: @MostafaSoliman that didn't help. I solved it by wrapping DBFF into `ButtonTheme` with `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded` parameter

Answer (score 27):

Change [`DropdownButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) to [`DropdownButtonFormField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html)  and add this decoration....

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Hexcolor('#ecedec'),
    labelText: 'Occupation',
    border: new CustomBorderTextFieldSkin().getSkin(),
  ),
  //...
)
```

Comment: Thanks dear, worked like charm :) Highly impression, recommend this answer

Answer (score 1):

> 

**Copy Paste and see magic**

I have done flutter dropdown with material design

```
    Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
          child: InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Priority',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            child: ButtonTheme(
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: const Text("Priority"),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: dropdownValue,
                elevation: 16,
                underline: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).