# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField labelText and dropdown spacing issue

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code in the `Row` that houses 2 `DropdownButtonFormField`

```
return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5.5, 0, 0),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(),
                      labelText: 'Gender'),
                  items: _genders,
                  value: client.gender,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      client.gender = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: formFieldSpace),
              Flexible(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5.5, 0, 0),
                    labelText: 'Marital Status',
                  ),
                  items: _maritals,
                  value: client.maritalStatus,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      client.maritalStatus = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

[image: asdf]

These are the list data:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _genders = [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: new Text("Male"),
      value: "Male",
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: new Text("Female"),
      value: "Female",
    ),
  ];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _maritals = [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: new Text("Single"),
      value: "Single",
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: new Text("Married"),
      value: "Married",
    ),
  ];
```

It shows up like the one in the image. My issue is how to remove the extra space between the decorator labelText like Gender and the dropdown button labeled "Male".

I cannot use a `ConstrainedBox` as it requires me to have to set width and height. Even if I set the width to double.infinity

Comment: Can you share `_genders` list with us?

Comment: my bad. added the lists.

Comment: You can go to this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64567403/10942128) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DropdownButtonFormField cannot be customised based on your requirement.
[Re: stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983783/set-height-of-dropdownbuttonformfield-list)

**Option #1**
Update the TextStyle of your DropdownMenuItems

[image: Dropdown text is closer to title]

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _genders = new List();
_genders.add(DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: 'Male',
  child: Text(
    'Male',
    style: TextStyle(height: 0.0),
  ),
));
_genders.add(DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: 'Female',
  child: Text(
    'Female',
    style: TextStyle(height: 0.0),
  ),
));
```

**Option #2**
Use DropdownButton instead

[image: Actual view of below code]

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Gender',
              style: TextStyle(),
            ),
            DropdownButton(
              items: _genders,
              value: client.gender,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  client.gender = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Marital Status',
              style: TextStyle(),
            ),
            DropdownButton(
              items: _maritals,
              value: client.maritalStatus,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  client.maritalStatus = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can also refer to this link for fresh ideas
[HOW TO CHANGE THE ITEM TEXT SIZE OF A DROPDOWNBUTTON IN FLUTTER](https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-change-the-item-text-size-of-a-dropdownbutton-in-flutter/)

Comment: after much trial and error, i went with option #2. though, if i pair this with a TextFormField the height of text+dropdownbutton is too big. i tried to look for a way inside DropdownButton to lessen its top padding but to no avail. got ideas?

Comment: I decided not to force the issue. im sure flutter will update these limitations so i just went with your option #2 together with a TextFormField but the dropdownbutton's Text (labelText) will be a bit higher than the TextFormField.